# django-allauth: do not let user sign in before email confirmation

Tags: django, django-allauth, email-verification

After signing up using the `django-allauth` behind-the-hood, the user gets **both** logged in **and** sent a verification email. The thing is, I want to let a user sign-in only **after** he has verified his email address.

How can I do it? I'm worried some user could spam my website with fake accounts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION='mandatory'`, by default this is set to `optional`

> Determines the e-mail verification method during signup – choose one
> of "mandatory", "optional", or "none".
>
> Setting this to “mandatory” requires ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED to be True
>
> When set to “mandatory” the user is blocked from logging in until the
> email address is verified. Choose “optional” or “none” to allow logins
> with an unverified e-mail address. In case of “optional”, the e-mail
> verification mail is still sent, whereas in case of “none” no e-mail
> verification mails are sent.

[Documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration)